# How to bind a RadGridView in RowDetailsTemplate of another RadGridView

Tags: wpf, telerik, wpf-controls, telerik-grid

A RadGridView is bound to a List (e.g., Samples). In RowDetailsTemplate I want to show another RadGridView that will show the related records from another List (e.g., Analysis).

The main RadGridView is bound at Code behind as:

```
GrdSamples.ItemsSource=SamplesViewModel.GetAll();
```

How can I bind the RadGridView in RowDetailsTemplate (GrdAnalysis) in the same way? And on which event I will get the key ID, So that I can use Something like:

```
var SampleID = ? 
GrdAnalysis.ItemsSource=AnalysisViewModel.Get(SampleID);
```

Here is the XAML,

```
 <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="GrdSamples" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
      <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>...</telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
         <telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="GrdAnalysis" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False">
          </DataTemplate>
      </telerik:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate> 
     </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `Loaded` event:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RadGridView inner = (RadGridView)sender;
    var sample = inner.DataContext as Sample;
    if (sample != null)
    {
        var SampleID = sample.Id;
        inner.ItemsSource = AnalysisViewModel.Get(SampleID);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataTemplate>
    <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="GrdAnalysis" Loaded="OnLoaded" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
</DataTemplate>
```

`Sample` is the type of objects returned by the `SamplesViewModel.GetAll()` method in the above sample code.